# iOS 8 wait for local notification permission

Tags: ios, ios8, uilocalnotification

I want to schedule a `UILocalNotification` when my app is first launched. On iOS 8 this requires me to ask for user permission with this call:

```
[application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
```

This brings up a dialog asking the user for permission.

Is there a way to wait for the users answer before scheduling my notification? I rather not wait for any other user action such a button press or view controller change in the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On iOS 8 and later, implement the following method in your AppDelegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {

    // You could check here [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings]

    // This is where you set up your local notification
}
```

This method is a `UIApplicationDelegate` method, so all you need to do is implement it in your `MyAppDelegate.m` file.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:):

> Tells the delegate what types of notifications may be used to get the user’s attention.
>
> Parameters
>
> application: The app object that registered the user notification settings.
>
> notificationSettings: The user notification settings that are available to your app.
>
> The settings in this object may be different than the ones you originally requested.
>
> Discussion
>
> Apps that use local or remote notifications to alert the user to new information must register the types of notifications they want to use by calling the registerUserNotificationSettings: method of the app object. (In apps that link on versions of iOS prior to 8.0, registration can also happen implicitly when you schedule a local notification.) Your app’s request is combined with the user’s current preferences to determine what notification types are allowed and the results are delivered to this method in the notificationSettings parameter.
>
> The first time you register your app’s preferred notification types, the system asks the user whether your app should be allowed to deliver notifications and stores the user’s response. The system does not prompt the user during subsequent registration attempts. The user can always change the notification preferences using the Settings app.
>
> Because the user’s preferences can change, you should always check the contents of the notificationSettings parameter. These settings control only whether the user is notified about a local or remote notification. The notification is still delivered to your app at the appropriate times.

Comment: No problem :) Do note that this method is only called on iOS 8! Notifications have suffered quite a few changes in this last update.